# передача/прием данных через сокеты

Tags: java

Имеется клиент серверное приложение.Между клиентом и сервером происходит обмен примитивными типами данных, для этого использую Data(Input/Output)Stream.

Имеется ли возможность как то определять какой тип пришел по DataInputStream, чтобы можно было его соответствующий образом считать(readUTF,readInt и т.д)?

Comment: Нет, такой возможности нет.

Comment: хм...а как тогда можно передавать по одному каналу различные типы данных?

Comment: Можно сначала передать тип данных, а потом сами данные.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса...

Сокет, лишь точка обмена данными приложения, по транспортному уровню, транспортному уровню в свою очередь, совершено не интересно что за данные он передаёт. Интерном это лишь прикладному уровню, на котором находится ваше приложения, соотвественно, если вам надо как-то работать с данными, все проверки, валидацию, и прочие, вы должны делать на прикладном уровне, то есть в вашем приложении.

Соотвественно обрабатывайте данные, на самом приложении, используйте готовые приложения, или примените какой-то прикладной протокол.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону grpc фрэймворка от гугла. Это по сути надстройка над http2. Protobuf протокол подразумевает строгую типизацию данных и строгое описание клиент серверного API (proto-file). Реализована генерация кода. "Из коробки" синхронные/асинхронные вызовы и потоковая работа с данными (стрим).
С практической стороны, сирилизация/десирилизация данных осуществляется на уровне работы самого протокола. В случае, если данные дескриптором не парсятся, будет транспортная ошибка, во всех остальных случаях вы будете иметь строго типизированные данные.